# java.net.SocketException while trying to send message with BufferedWriter

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I am trying to make a simple client/server application using Socket, BufferedReader and BufferedWriter. Authorization works good, and when i am sending first message everything also works, but when i am trying to send second message i catch the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Канал обірвано
    at utils.SocketManager.writeMsg(SocketManager.java:33)
    at client.Chat.sendMessage(Chat.java:53)
    at client.Chat.lambda$new$0(Chat.java:37)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6620)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4995)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Канал обірвано
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:413)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:433)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:812)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1120)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:409)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:414)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.lockedFlush(StreamEncoder.java:218)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:205)
    at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:263)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.implFlush(BufferedWriter.java:372)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:359)
    at utils.SocketManager.writeMsg(SocketManager.java:31)
    ... 37 more
```

Here is piece of server code:

```
private static void handleClient(Socket socket){
                try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(
                                socket.getOutputStream()));
                     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                             new InputStreamReader(
                                     socket.getInputStream()))) {
        
                    String command = "";
                    while(!command.equals("Exit")) {//here starts endless loop
                        if (reader.ready()) {
                            command = reader.readLine();
                            switch (command) {
                                case "LogIn" -> logIn(writer, reader);
                                case "SendMsg" -> sendMsg(reader);
                                case "Exit" -> {
                                    clients.remove(socket);
                                    socket.close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
         private static void sendMsg(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException{
                String message = reader.readLine();
        
                for(Socket client : clients) {
                    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(
                                    client.getOutputStream()))) {
                        writer.write(message);
                        writer.newLine();
                        writer.flush();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Client:

```
public Chat(String login) {
        this.login = login;

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ReceiveMessage());
        thread.start();

        sendButton.addActionListener(e -> sendMessage());
    }

    public void openFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame("YurChat");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);

        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        frame.setBounds(toolkit.getScreenSize().width / 2 - 325, toolkit.getScreenSize().height / 2 - 200, 550, 300);
    }

    private void sendMessage() {
        SocketManager.writeMsg("SendMsg");//server does not get command second time
        String message = login + ":\t" + messageTextField.getText();
        SocketManager.writeMsg(message);//throws exception
        messageTextField.setText("");
    }

    private class ReceiveMessage implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                if(SocketManager.isReaderReady()) {
                    String msg = SocketManager.readMsg();
                    chatTextArea.append(msg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SocketManager:

```
public final class SocketManager {
    private static final Socket socket;
    private static final BufferedWriter writer;
    private static final BufferedReader reader;

    static {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(
                    PropertiesUtil.getProperty("socket.ip"),
                    Integer.parseInt(PropertiesUtil.getProperty("socket.port")));
            writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(
                            socket.getOutputStream()));
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            socket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void writeMsg(String message) {
        try {
            writer.write(message);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String readMsg() {
        try {
            return reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isReaderReady() {
        try {
            return reader.ready();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void close() {
        try {
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Full code is here: https://github.com/lucifer116664/ClientServerChat.git

I debugged this app and found that when i am sending message second time client is sending command "SendMsg", but server does not get it and stops in the endless loop waiting for command.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly the client is sending, and what do you expect server to do?

Comment: “…but when i am trying to send second message i catch the exception.”  Edit your question, and include the full stack trace of the exception you’re getting, including all `Caused by` sections.  That stack trace will tell you, and us, what went wrong and where.  Without that information, we can only guess what your problem is.

Comment: Client is sending the command, for example "SendMsg", and then some data (message). Command is needed server to know what exactly client wants to do (authorization, registration, sening message...). Server is putting this command to switch case, and reading next data from client. If command is "SendMsg" server is reading the message sent by client and sends it to every user.

Comment: Please translate 'Канал обірвано'. And get rid of the `reader.ready()` test. It's pointless. You don't have the option of not reading the next message. Otherwise you will cause an application protocol error and maybe this one.

Comment: The channel is broken

Comment: I tried to run this code without reader.ready(), exception has not disapeared

Comment: Sounds like 'connection reset' or 'broken pipe'. There are many causes but one of them is either peer closing the socket without having read all the data that was sent.

Comment: By the way, user207421 if i am not using reader.ready() server throws this while sending first message:
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
at server.Server.handleClient(Server.java:58)
 at server.Server.lambda$main$0(Server.java:27)
...
at server.Server.handleClient(Server.java:46)

Comment: 'Socket closed' means that *you* closed the socket and then continued to use it. You're missing a `break` after `socket.close()` in the "Exit" case.

Comment: I can't use break, because it is in the switch case. That is why i put condition in the while loop.

Comment: You closed the socket in `sendMsg` because of the try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mark Rotteveel i got the answer.
I just modified sendMsg method by putting try with resources into if(client != socket) (sending message everyone besides client who wrote it) and everything works great.

```
    private static void sendMsg(Socket socket, BufferedReader reader) throws IOException{
            String message = reader.readLine();
    
            for(Socket client : clients) {
                if(client != socket) {
                    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(
                                    client.getOutputStream()))) {
                        writer.write(message);
                        writer.newLine();
                        writer.flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```